# Display existing images as cropped thumbnail (and keep aspect ratio) in Dropzone.js instead of squished images?

Tags: dropzone.js

When I upload images to Dropzone.js they keep their aspect ratio and just get cropped.
They look like this which is good:

[image]

When I use this code to display previously uploaded files:

```
...
         $.getJSON('files/list-all', function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index, val) {
                var mockFile = { name: val.name, size: val.size };
                thisDropZone.options.addedfile.call(thisDropZone, mockFile);
                thisDropZone.options.thumbnail.call(thisDropZone, mockFile, "uploads/" + val.id + "." + val.extension);
            });
        });
...
```

I get these squished versions of the images:

[image]

So the question is how do I get the thumbnails to look good like they when you upload?

Comment: Also I'm curious what would be the correct way to add the green (V) icon and the removal option? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Meanwhile for the development phase I used Croppa, a Laravel bundle.

Answer (score 9):

Same problem, my workaround. It's not the cropped effect, but keeps the aspect ratio. It also centers the picture within the frame.

It goes by implementing the 'fileadded' listener in the 'init' option on dropzone creation. Then, adjust the image.

Steps:

1. Finds the IMG element in the preview frame;
2. Waits for the image to be loaded (the dimensions aren't available before);
3. Retrieves its dimensions;
4. Computes the aspect ratio, pretended dimensions and position;
5. Defines inline css (overriding the css class 'dropzone').

Listing:

```
var thisDropZone = new Dropzone($("#thisDropZone"), {
    url: "files/upload",
    init: function () {
        this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
            var img = $(file.previewTemplate).find("img");
            img[0].onload = function () {
                var max = this.width > this.height ? this.width : this.height;
                var ratio = 100.0 / max;

                var width = this.width * ratio;
                var height = this.height * ratio;

                img.css({
                    width: width + "px",
                    height: height + "px",
                    top: ((100 - height) / 2) + "px",
                    left: ((100 - width) / 2) + "px"
                });
            };
        }
    }
});
```

The recurring magic number '100' is the 'width' and 'weight' property values for IMG element, as defined by the css class '.dropzone' in theirs default stylesheet 'dropzone.css'.

To achieve this, you can't call the 'addedfile' event like you do; you have to trigger it like this:

```
$.getJSON('files/list-all', function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, val) {
        var mockFile = { name: val.name, size: val.size };

        thisDropZone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
        thisDropZone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, "uploads/" + val.id + "." + val.extension);
    });
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to generate a thumbnail and store it with the original image? Otherwise you're downloading the full sized images.